# How can I declare a class in my structure?

Tags: c++

This is my .hpp

```
class playerBat
{
    public:
        playerBat(int x, int y);
        sf::RectangleShape *getShape();
        void setShape(sf::RectangleShape *Shape);
    private:
        sf::RectangleShape shapeBat;
};

typedef struct s_game_elements
{
    playerBat playerOne(int, int);
    playerBat playerTwo(int, int);
} t_game_elements;
```

And this is how I initialize it :

```
t_game_elements gameElements;

playerBat playerBatOne(0, 200);
playerBat playerBatTwo(790, 200);

gameElements.playerOne = playerBatOne;
gameElements.playerTwo = playerBatTwo;
```

But the compilator says:

```
src/main.cpp:14:18: error: reference to non-static member function must be called gameElements.playerOne = playerBatOne;
```

What did I do wrong ? 
Sorry if it is something very obvious but I started to learn CPP recently and I never had this error in C.

Comment: `playerOne` is a function. You're trying to assign a function. Get rid of the `(int, int)` parameters if you just want a variable (i.e. `playerBat playerOne;`).

Comment: I am trying to assign to my structure the class playerBat, so what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Cornstalks I have the error `no matching constructor for initialization of 't_game_elements' (aka 's_game_elements') ` if I do that, how can I fix it ?

Comment: If a member doesn't have a default constructor, you must construct it in the initialization list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
typedef struct  s_game_elements
{
    playerBat   playerOne;
    playerBat   playerTwo;
}
```

Otherwise in this typedef declaration the struture has two functions instead of data members  of type playerBat

```
typedef struct  s_game_elements
{
    playerBat   playerOne(int, int);
    playerBat   playerTwo(int, int);
}
```

Take into account that there is a typo

```
t_game_elements gameElements;
^^^
```

Early the typedef name in the typedef declaration looked like

```
s_game_elements
^^^
```

Comment: Thanks ! 
I don't have the typo in my code, I just did the copy / past wrong :s 
However I have an error I cannot understand, it's `implicit default constructor for 's_game_elements' must explicitly initialize the member 'playerOne' which does not have a default constructor ` , got an idea ?

Comment: @DimitriDanilov Class playerBat does not have the default constructor. In this case the other class is unable to initialize its data members.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov Either define the default constructor in class playerBat or define the default constructor in struct s_game_elements and call playerBat's constructor in mem-initializer list or use in this structure a braced initializers.